# Should we commit IDE settings in the VCS?

Tags: version-control, ide

We're working mainly in Java, using both Eclipse and Intellij in the team.
We had a discussion in the team about committing IDE settings (.iml, .project) on our git.

I'm against this practice, but someone pointed me the fact that would be much easier for everyone to be aligned on the same settings like code style and warnings.

Also they showed me as modern browsers do a good job of separating local machine specific stuff from project specific ones.

Is there are reason why we shouldn't commit them?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/445187/to-check-in-or-not-check-in-the-entire-eclipse-project

Comment: Yes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116121/do-you-keep-your-project-files-under-version-control/119377#119377, or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337304/which-eclipse-files-belong-under-version-control/337317#337317

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason why you could avoid version those files is if they contains developer-specific data (paths that are only valid for one developer and not others, some value which are only relevant on one workstation and not others).

Any other files that:

- can be reused by any developer
- help get back an environment able to re-build the program with identical settings

should be put in the VCS.
And that include any IDE setting files, as I mention in "[Do you keep your project files under version control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116121/do-you-keep-your-project-files-under-version-control/119377#119377)", or "[Which eclipse files belong under Version Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337304/which-eclipse-files-belong-under-version-control/337317#337317)".